# Printed contents disappear in terminal

Tags: terminal

The thing is I have printed something in the terminal, but when I accidentally resize the terminal, the printed contents at the bottom of my terminal disappear. Why is that? Is there anyway to recover these printed messages since the program runs a long time each time.

Comment: There's no practical way to do this, since the terminal isn't likely to have a copy of the information any longer.  (Dredging through the process memory is impractical).

Comment: Thanks! But why this happens? I just dragged the edge of the terminal a little bit, why some of the contents disappear? @Thomas Dickey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you resize a terminal window, the terminal has to paint or repaint part of the window.  If you lost text at the **bottom** of the window, that sounds as if you **shrank** the window when using one of the terminals which leave the upper-left corner of the window in a fixed position, while adjusting the rest of the window.  Offhand, that could be rxvt, putty, konsole.  xterm (which is configurable) defaults to the other direction.

If the window shrinks, then the location of the "bottom" row of text should be moved up (to match user's expectations).  But there is a complication: GNU screen will besides redrawing the window, *attempt* to wrap long lines so that they fit the new margins.  Developers for a few terminals have imitated that in the past few years, and you may notice some bug reports when that new feature does not work well.

For instance, if you shrank the window vertically, but changed its width, then a miscalculation of the wrapped lines could cause text to vanish.  Then again, resizing it again might get the text back into view.  But if that does not work, then it's **gone**.